# Error on importing an Eclipse project into Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, gradle, android-appcompat

I'm trying to import a project done in Eclipse to Android Studio. While importing, I'm getting the following error:

```
"There are unrecoverable errors which must be corrected first"

Library reference ../../../../workspace/android-support-v7-appcompat could not be found
```

I tried copying appcompat folder to the root directory of project, still same error. How can I resolve it?

Please refer the screenshot for more details[image: error details]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Finally, I found a way..I opened the `project.properties` file in a text editor and removed the line which was related to `appcompat`. Then I managed to import the project without errors. After successful import, I added `appcompat` as a dependency as answered by Gabriele Mariotti. Thanks Gabriele Mariotti.

Answer (score 5):

Dont' copy the appcompat library as a module in Android Studio.

Just add this dependency in your app/build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3"
}
```

Where the structure of your project is:

```
root
  app
     build.gradle  <-- here
  build.gradle  //top level
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the project itself is not getting imported to edit the app/build.gradle file.