# Android : unable to open eclipse project in android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, import, eclipse-adt

I have a problem to Open Eclipse ADT project in Android Studio. I have Eclipse project folder, structure is [Image_Eclipse Folder/File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcKgt.png)

When I select main folder and click Next then the screen appear **Import from Eclipse ADT** and the Path of the project.[Image_Import From Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0J6V.png)
 After Clicking Next there are 3 checkbox appear, put all check and click next then the above screen appear. Which shows `android-support-v7-appcompat` problem. And when click finish it shows **There are unrecoverable errors which must be corrected first**

Is there any missing term or file in the above Structure?
or any other problem? please help .. Thanks

Comment: check this link it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16584263/how-do-i-open-my-existing-eclipse-projects-in-android-studio

Comment: Check this one:
[Error on importing an Eclipse project into Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28701237/error-on-importing-an-eclipse-project-into-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Android studio could not support without gradle files,so first generate grdale file from eclipse,

Eclipse:
Open eclipse ->select project ->right click ->Export ->Select android folder ->Select generate gradle build file and select your location.

Android Studio:

open Android studio ->open project->select above location then open build.gradle file